# just guest session available, can not login

Tags: boot, apt, nvidia, login

I'm desperately trying to login into ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After boot I see the guest session asking for my password. After login it appears a black screen for just a half second and I will redirect to the previous login screen.

Yesterday, I installed a ppa for gvfs and gvfs itself via apt but that didn't work correctly so I removed both. After reboot, the described situation started. I checked the gvfs package and tried a lot of recommended commands and finally it seems to be fixed. Furthermore, I reinstalled my nvidia drivers and deleted this .Xauthority file in my home folder.

Every clue is welcome!

Update: Also deleted /tmp/.x0-lock. Didn't help

Comment: I had a similar problem with .Xauth file. It was created with root permissions and I couldn't log in because it couldn't be opened as rw.

Answer (score 1):

just delete the file ~/.Xauthority and reboot  , this should solve your issue

Comment: As already said, I removed this file as root in my user home.

Comment: i had the same issue and removed it as the normal user not the root  and rebooted  and i could log in normally

Comment: and i see in your issue you deleted another file

Comment: I just didn't know the exact name anymore. Deleted again as user but didn't work either. Thanks nevertheless.